# Is there anyway I can add a current processing id to each button?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to add html code to the current clicked button but when I click the next button it adds the html code to the first button.

First button clicked:
[image: First Button Clicked]

Second button clicked
[image: Second Button Clicked]

This code works very well.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.approve', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var orderId = $(this).attr('id');
    var customerEmail = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var customerName = $('#orderFormAp').attr('action');

    $.ajax({
      url: 'action.php?action=approveOrder',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {orderId:orderId, customerEmail:customerEmail, customerName:customerName},
      beforeSend: function()
      {
        $('#' + orderId).prop('disabled', 'true');
        $('#' + orderId).html('Approving...');
      },
      success: function(response)
      {
        $('#' + orderId).prop('disabled', 'false');
        $('#' + orderId).html('Approve');
        loadOrders();
      }
    });
  });
```

This is the code for the other button. When I click it adds the HTML to the first button. This also happens when I click the third button.

```
  $(document).on('click', '.cancel', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var orderId = $(this).attr('id');
    var customerEmail = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var customerName = $('#orderFormAp').attr('action');

    $.ajax({
      url: 'action.php?action=cancelOrder',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {orderId:orderId, customerEmail:customerEmail, customerName:customerName},
      beforeSend: function()
      {
        $('#' + orderId).prop('disabled', 'true');
        $('#' + orderId).html('Canceling...');
      },
      success: function(response)
      {
        $('#' + orderId).prop('disabled', 'false');
        $('#' + orderId).html('Cancel');
        loadOrders();
      }
    });
  });
```

My form looks like this.

```
  <form id="orderFormAp" action="' . $order['first_name'] . '" method="post">
    <button type="submit" id="' . $order['id'] . '" data-id="' . $order['email'] . '" name="approve" class="btn approve">Approve</button>
    <button type="submit" id="' . $order['id'] . '" data-id="' . $order['email'] . '" name="dispatch" class="btn dispatch">Dispatch</button>
    <button type="submit" id="' . $order['id'] . '" data-id="' . $order['email'] . '" name="cancel" class="btn cancel">Cancel</button>
  </form>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? The script processes the PHP code correctly but the buttons are not.

Comment: I am assuming that `$order['id']` will be the same for all 3 of those buttons. An `id` has to be UNIQUE on the page for javascript to work properly when addressing it by `id`

Comment: How can I achieve that?

Comment: Instead of doing `id="xxx"` and selecting it via `.attr('id')`, get rid of the `id` attribute completely, add a new `data-` attribute like this `data-order_id="{$order['id']}"` and select it with `.attr('data-order_id')`

Comment: I tried doing that but html no longer applied on buttons.

Comment: I also tried making the IDs unique like this but still not working. data-approve="$order['id']" and  data-cancel="$order['id']".

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem to my question. I added the clicked button class to the selector of each button and it works.

```
  beforeSend: function()
  {
    $('#' + orderId + '.approve').prop('disabled', 'true');
    $('#' + orderId + '.approve').html('Approving...');
  },
  success: function(response)
  {
    $('#' + orderId + '.approve').prop('disabled', 'false');
    $('#' + orderId + '.approve').html('Approve');
    loadOrders();
  }
```